# matlab - removing elements with low frequency in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, frequency

If you have a MATLAB array such as the below:

> > A = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]

I want to be able to filter this array so that elements which have a low frequency are removed.

In other words, is there an easy way to remove elements in the array which have a certain low frequency for example <= than 2?

In this case:

The result would be:

> > [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]

Cheers

Comment: So walk along the array, checking if the next element is equivalent to the previous one.  Keep a count and remove that many elements.  You can use the changing value of the array length to control when you run out of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do it somehow like this (hope the syntax is good :))

```
function array= ClearElementsWithLowOccurence(array,minimalFrequency)
elements = unique(array);
indecesToRemove = [];
for i = 0:length(elements)
   indeces = find(array==elements(i));
   if (length(indeces) < minimalFrequency)
      indecesToRemove = [indecesToRemove indeces];
   end;
end;
array(indecesToRemove) = [];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick way. `A` does not need to be sorted, the numbers can be anything.

```
A = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5];

%# count the numbers in A (use unique so that the array
%# remains at a decent size even if the values are very different)
[uniqueEntries,~,idx] = unique(A);
counts = histc(idx,1:max(idx));

%# remove all the numbers whose count is less or equal than two
A(ismember(A,uniqueEntries(counts<=2))) = []
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the problem you've posted does not belong to a single domain, but can be encountered almost everywhere, i'll go with pseudocode. I hope thats not too much of a problem/irritation.

here's what you can do

1. Take variables

   - LIMIT: the minimum frequency required for an element to survive 
       (2 in this case)
   - ELEMENT: the value of the present array element
2. Now, for-each (new) ELEMENT encountered, do the following:

   - check the element LIMIT ahead of ELEMENT
   - if it equals ELEMENT, this value will be retained, and continue in the same way to
     the next value (now ELEMENT) until the array has been fully traversed.
   - If not, remove all occurrences of this value., and again continue.....

   Finally, you end up with the required array.